# What is your advice on reaching out to an external mentor to judge a research idea I am working on?

Tags: research-process, advisor, etiquette, supervision, mentoring

I am working on a research idea and my advisor is not helping much, he is leaving me on my own. I thought a conversation with someone knowledgeable in the field would be good or even a collaboration. As an international master's student, how do I approach external professors that don't know me in such a case but, without much awkwardness or me looking needy?

I thought of the following:

1. Introducing myself.
2. Tell them I am doing research on topic X for ex "optimization" and I have an idea that I am working on and would love to hear about others' perspectives on it.
3. Ask if they know someone who I can reach out to who might be interested in discussing this idea.
4. Thank them.

What do you think? and what are the things that I should never put in an email to them?

Comment: It's not the question you asked, but here goes anyway. If you can't talk to your advisor about this, then you have another problem. See if you can solve that problem.

Comment: If the idea is good, the person you sent it to may work on it, and publish it first.    This has happened many times.  Search other questions on this forum.

Answer (score 4):

Put yourself in the shoes of the person that you are writing to. Because you selected someone important, X (the person that you selected) will be busy and receive a certain number of emails. Each email takes out a certain amount of time from X's schedule. Some of these emails are from people that want something such as a way to study under X, even though a close reading will show that they actually do not know what X is interested in. Some of these emails will ask for help in reviewing, ... X will probably have given up trying to answer all of these emails and will only have a single glance at the email.

You are a stranger to X, so if you write a long nice email, it is still quite possible that X will not even answer you because X has not read your email. You are also asking a lot. X has Ph.D. students on their own and X might be struggling to find time for them. Trying to think about somebody else to mentor you is also difficult, as X does not want to impose on their academic friends.

It is much better to set up a connection through some mutual acquaintance.
*See, your real problem is that you do not feel helped by your advisor and you do not seem to think that you could ask your advisor to find you someone to discuss your idea.* But you presumably take classes or attend lectures at your institution. If you approach someone personally, they are more likely to at least listen to your request. Someone else on the faculty might have a connection to X and if your email comes with a recommendation of someone else, then your email will have passed through the initial screening.

If you have to use email, the best strategy to get your email even read is to have the other person emotionally involved. If X has written on your topic and your idea plays off on of X's papers, then you can use this as a starting point: "I read your paper and I am wondering whether this idea of mine would not expand on your idea". This makes it clear that there is something in it for X.

**TLTR:**In short, you need to get X's attention and you need to make any type of mentoring worth-while for X. Email is going to be a difficult medium. But your real problem is your relationship with your advisor, and that is **your** problem and not X's problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the advisor is the best person to connect you with someone else; someone in their circle of collaboration. This might be possible as long as the advisor isn't hostile.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add a bit to the [answer of Thomas Schwarz](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/189246/75368). First, I'll repeat the comment that your advisor is the best person to connect you with someone else, assuming you think it is wise to ask.

If that is impossible, perhaps there is another faculty member you trust who can either help or can put you in touch with one of their contacts. An email from a professor won't be ignored where one from a student might be.

But, and thinking of other questions you've asked here, this is one of the reasons you want to go to conferences as a young scholar. There will be people there who can likely help you and might be willing. Even your poster session is a good place to grab people who seem especially interested in your poster and ask if they have a few moments for some back-and-forth over coffee or whatever.

Or, go to a talk by someone close to your academic specialty and stay afterwards for a chat. Ask for advice. Ask for permission to contact them after the conference ends.

But as the linked answer suggests, blind emails are too easily ignored.

Long term, build yourself a circle of collaborators. A good start is to get yourself connected to that of your advisor. You don't have to plan to write papers with everyone in your circle, but you want a bunch of people you can talk to.